# How to get the "originally requested" URL when using IIRF URL Rewriting Engine

Tags: iis, seo, url-rewriting, iirf

I am using Iconic's [IIRF URL Rewriting Engine](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/IIRF.aspx) on IIS and the "fancy" URLs are something like this:

```
http://some-website.com/some-function/418/some-keyword-rich-filename.html
```

This example URL corresponds to:

```
http://some-website.com/some-function.asp?SOME-ID=418
```

Now inside the some-function.asp file I need to know the page that was requested by the browser. I went through all IIS variables but wasn't able to find the value `/some-function/418/some-keyword-rich-filename.html` inside any of them.

As a side note, I need this information to send 301 redirect to browsers. E.g. if the browser requests:

```
http://some-website.com/some-function/418/index.html
```

I first need to send the browser to:

```
http://some-website.com/some-function/418/some-keyword-rich-filename.html
```

And this is why I need the original url for comparison.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For IIRF, this is called **unmangling** and can be achieved by using the modifier `U`.

From the [IIRF manual](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf21Help/html/bdaf0dbe-e539-4bf5-9231-1dae3b0e27a5.htm#Modifiers):

> U = Store original url in server
>   variable HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL

Simply add the modifier `U` to the `RewriteRule` for which you would like to retain the original url. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^/some-function/(\d+)/(.*)$ /some-function.asp?SOME-ID=$1 [I,U,L]
```

Then, in the code of your page `some-function.asp`, you may access the original url like this (classic ASP):

```
Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL")
```