# How to read rewritten url in asp.net 3.5

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting, iirf

How to read the rewritten url. If I don't use .aspx in my rewritten url then 'Request.RawUrl' is not working. It is returning the original URL.

Please suggest if you have any solution to this. I am using Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter (IIRF).

For example, if I have rewrite:

```
http://<mywebsite>/users.aspx?id=12&name=amitava
```

to

```
http://<mywebsite>/profile/12/amitava
```

Now in the same page, at some point, I want to get this rewrittern url for the purpose of pointing return url in login link. Now a login link should be:

```
http://<mywebsite>/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/profile/12/amitava
```

or

```
http://<mywebsite>/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=http://<mywebsite>/profile/12/amitava
```

What is the proper way to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For IIRF, this is called **unmangling** and can be achieved by using the modifier `U`.

From the [IIRF manual](http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/Iirf21Help/html/bdaf0dbe-e539-4bf5-9231-1dae3b0e27a5.htm#Modifiers):

> U = Store original url in server
>   variable HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL

Simply add the modifier `U` to the `RewriteRule` for which you would like to retain the original url. For example:

```
RewriteRule ^yourexpression$ yourrewrittenurl [I,U,L]
```

Then, in the code of your page, you may access the original url like this:

```
Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL")
```

See also my [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5432617/63733)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the IIS rewriting module?
If you are then `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` should give you the rewritten URL and `HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.OriginalString` should give you the non-rewritting URL.

Comment: I am using IIRF rewriting module

Comment: Tried Request.RawUrl but it is returning the non-rewritten url

Comment: Okay I got the answer. It is here and working  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3895956/how-to-get-the-originally-requested-url-when-using-iirf-url-rewriting-engine